# Hadoop - Map and reduce stuck at 0% all the time

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to implement the PageRank algorithm on Hadoop platform with Eclipse, but I'm facing some unusual problems :). I tried this locally: installed cygwin, set up Hadoop 0.19.2 (and 0.18.0), started the necessary daemons and installed Eclipse 3.3.1. I uploaded testinf .txt file and then tried to run the WordCount example or even a simple .java  and I got this output (for about 100 times :)) ):

> 10/07/22 22:10:23 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
>   10/07/22 22:10:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201007220415_0017
>   10/07/22 22:10:24 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%

Map and reduce are 0% all the time. I tried with Hadoop on virtual machine and I got the same situation.

I followed all the instructions from Hadoop page and other useful pages, but it didn't resolve my problem. Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a problem more with your Hadoop setup than with Eclipse. Make sure you have all the pieces of your cluster running, i.e. DataNode(s), TaskTracker(s), JobTracker. If those are all running, it might be a problem with the way you're setting up the job.

Answer (score 0):

Are you bent to-do this in Java?  If not you can use a Ruby gem called WUKONG that has a pagerank example http://github.com/mrflip/wukong/tree/master/examples/pagerank/